# ECS Scheduled Task not executing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, amazon-ecr

I have an ECS Scheduled task that is supposed to run every 6 hours. Below is the cdk code:

```
  const ecrRepository = ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryArn(
    this,
    'My Scheduler',
    'arn:aws:ecr:ap-southeast-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:repository/my-scheduler'
  );

  const mySchedulerTask = new ScheduledFargateTask(this, 'myScheduler', {
    schedule: Schedule.expression('rate(6 hours)'),
    cluster: cluster,
    desiredTaskCount: 1,
    vpc: vpc,
    scheduledFargateTaskImageOptions: {
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(ecrRepository, 'latest'),
      environment: {
        
      },
      secrets: {
        
      }
    }
  });
  ecrRepository.grantPull(mySchedulerTask.taskDefinition.executionRole as IRole);
```

I even separately added CloudWatch Rules and added the task as target.

```
  new Rule(this, 'rule1', {
    schedule: Schedule.cron({hour: '14', minute: '0'}),
    targets: [ new targets.EcsTask(mySchedulerTask)]
  });
  

  new Rule(this, 'rule2', {
    schedule: Schedule.cron({hour: '20', minute: '0'}),
    targets: [ new targets.EcsTask(mySchedulerTask)]
  });
  
  new Rule(this, 'rule3', {
    schedule: Schedule.cron({hour: '02', minute: '0'}),
    targets: [ new targets.EcsTask(mySchedulerTask)]
  });

  new Rule(this, 'rule4', {
    schedule: Schedule.cron({hour: '08', minute: '0'}),
    targets: [ new targets.EcsTask(mySchedulerTask)]
  });
```

I can see in Clusters that it has 5 tasks with 4 new schedules and one defined in task. But none of them seem to be invoked as upon looking at metrics I can see the invocation count but can't see anything in logs.

I have confirmed that the docker image exists in ECR. The code is running successfully from local machine so no issue with code.

Comment: You should check in AWS CloudTrail for failed task creation event.

Comment: I looked into the the CloudTrail log too but didn't see any failures. However, I was bit suspicious about assignPublicIP but for some reason SchedulerFargateTask didn't have this property to set so couldn't set it to true. Also, now I look more carefully I see container lastStatus is pending, I will have to check if it could be the issue. https://imgur.com/HwBhe11